# Why directory takes up more space than it actually is?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I use FreeNAS (on FreeBSD) with ZFS file system. 
One directory (only one) takes up more space than it actually is.
I've checked folder size it is 720Gb, but if I check space on file system i see that it takes 1292Gb.
Tell me, what could it be.
[how i check space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBkem.png)

Comment: You are measuring two different things. Take a look at [this q&a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage) on U&L.

Comment: I guess, the size of "zfs pool" is 1292Gb and the "dataset"(folder) uses 720Gb from it. You might want to post the output of "zpool list" and "zfs list". Here is [ZFS overview](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/zfs/) with complete references in the end.

Comment: Note that they're called "directories", not "folders". Folders is not the same thing and is, essentially, a Windows term.

Comment: Keep in mind that the FreeNAS has a soft limit of 80% of available disk space i.e. zvols can't even be created with more than 80% as their designated size: https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2/storage.html#adding-zvols